# Javascript triggered CSS animation breaks after first use

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have an element that is hidden by default but comes into view when a button is clicked. I achieve this by applying a class which contains a CSS animation for a smooth transition, there is another class with the same animation reversed that should play when the button is clicked a second time. However, on the second - and on every subsequent click - the animation does not play, instead the element switches immediately to the animation's completed state.

```js
function setup() {
  card = document.getElementById("postCard");
  if (document.getElementById("spinMode")) {
    document.getElementById("spinMode").addEventListener("click", spinMode)
  };

}

var card;
var contactSide = false;

function spinMode() {

  if (contactSide) {
    contactSide = false;
    card.classList.remove("flip");
    card.classList.add("unflip");
  } else {

    contactSide = true;
    card.classList.remove("unflip");
    card.classList.add("flip");
  };

}

window.addEventListener("load", setup);
card = document.getElementById("postCard");
```

```css
* {
  perspective: 1600px;
}

#postCard {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  width: 400px;
  height: 250px;
  position: relative;
}

.cardSize {
  background-color: floralwhite;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  /* Safari */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip {
  animation: 00.5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1) 0s forwards infoOut;
  -webkit-animation: 00.5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1) 0s forwards infoOut;
}

.unflip {
  animationDirection: reverse;
  animation: 00.5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1) 0s backwards infoOut;
  -webkit-animation: 00.5s cubic-bezier(.19, 1, .22, 1) 0s backwards infoOut;
}

form p {
  text-align: center;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px white;
}

#postCard .front {
  /*transform: rotateY(85deg);*/
}

#postCard .back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  /*animation-delay:    4s;*/
  /*animation:          08.0s linear 0s infinite forwards infoOut; */
  /*-webkit-animation:  08.0s linear 0s infinite forwards infoOut; */
}

@keyframes infoOut {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}

#spinMode {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="postCard">
  <img class="cardSize front" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Olympic_Rainforest_Hiker.jpg">
  <form class="cardSize back" name="postCard" action="mailto:paulallen@pierceandpierce.biz" method="post" enctype="text/plain">

    <p>Paul Allen<br>Vice President</p>

  </form>
</div>

<button id="spinMode">Flip.</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easiest, in my opinion, with `transition` instead of `animation`. Set the `transition` property on the main style section. Set the `transform` property to be true when `.flip` is active. No `.unFlip` needed.

```js
function setup(){
    card = document.getElementById("postCard");
    if(document.getElementById("spinMode")){
        document.getElementById("spinMode").addEventListener("click", spinMode)
    };
    
}

var card;
var contactSide = false;
    
function spinMode(){
    
    if(contactSide){
        contactSide = false;
        card.classList.remove("flip");
    }else{
        
        contactSide = true;
        card.classList.add("flip");
    };
    
}
        
window.addEventListener("load", setup);card = document.getElementById("postCard");
```

```css
*{
  perspective: 1600px;
}

#postCard{
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    
    width:400px;     
  height:250px;
    position:relative;
        transition: transform .5s cubic-bezier(.19,1,.22,1);
}

.cardSize{
  background-color: floralwhite;
    width: 100%;            
    height: 100%;           
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* Safari */   
    backface-visibility: hidden;                        
}

.flip{
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

form p{
  text-align: center;
  font-variant:small-caps;  
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin:0;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px white;
}

#postCard .front{
    /*transform: rotateY(85deg);*/
}

#postCard .back{                  
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    
    transform: rotateY(180deg);                                   
    
    /*animation-delay:  4s;*/                                         
    /*animation:            08.0s linear 0s infinite forwards infoOut; */
    /*-webkit-animation:    08.0s linear 0s infinite forwards infoOut; */
}

#spinMode{
    position:absolute;
    top:4px;
    left: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="postCard">
    <img  class="cardSize front" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a3/Olympic_Rainforest_Hiker.jpg">
  <form class="cardSize back" name="postCard" action="mailto:paulallen@pierceandpierce.biz" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
        
    <p>Paul Allen<br>Vice President</p>
  
    </form>
</div>

<button id="spinMode">Flip.</button>
```